# django related_name queries and self not the same object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have something like:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    pass

class SubThing(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing, related_name='subthings')
    a = models.DecimalField()
    # some more Decimal fields

    def __str__():
        return str(self.pk) + ' - ' + str(self.a)

    def save():
        self.a = 0
        print(self)  # outputs 187 - 0
        print(self.thing.subthings.all()) # outputs ... 187 - 20 ...
        # do some calculations on self and siblings
        Super(SubThing, self).save()
```

I am confused by the output of the code above. I need to recalculate siblings of SubThing when it is saved, under certain conditions. The query `self.thing.subthings.all()` includes `self`, and since I couldn't exclude it reliably (`.exclude(self)` doesn't seem to work, and for a new instance `pk` is `None`), I chose to `self.a = 0` which would give me the behaviour I need.

However, `self` and the object in `self.thing.subthings.all()` don't hold the same values, while both have `pk=187` according to the output.

Are they both the same object and not? Is there some caching happening with `related_name` that breaks my logic?

How would I get the change `self.a = 0` reflected in the queryset?

Comment: They are definitely *not* the same object. And the reason they don't have the same value is that you're doing the `subthings` query before you've saved the new value to the database. I don't understand what you're trying to do well enough to offer a solution, perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: when I save SubThing, in some cases I need to iterate over its siblings (the ones linked to its Thing) and change values in them and resave them. The whole treatment is encapsulated in a transaction to ensure that data remains consistent overall.

Comment: But what is the problem you're facing in doing that? If you're trying to exclude the `self` row from further processing, just skip the object in the `subthings` query that has the same PK. Is that your question, how to do that? And is there a reason why you're doing `setattr(self, 'a', 0)` rather `self.a = 0`?

Comment: My question is about why changing attributes on `self` isn't reflected on the query result `self.thing.subthings.all()`.I can probably get around the issue by skipping the object as you describe (although if `self.pk == None` how do I filter for it?), but I'm trying to understand how I would get my changes reflected in the queryset.

Comment: I updated the question. I used setattr(self, 'a', 0) initially because my real code actually loops over a list of attributes. But I dont' think this impacts the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting attributes on the Python model instance does not cause your database to change. That is the purpose of the `save()` method. So if you want to see your saved changes to the instance reflected in your subsequent query, you need to do the model saving first.

```
    def save():
        self.a = 0
        super(SubThing, self).save()  # persists your changes to the database

        self.thing.subthings.all()  # will reflect the updated value
        # do stuff
```